# Is WB.SE participating in the Hat Contest?

Tags: discussion

Good news! The Winter Bash has started!

Will WB.SE be participating this year?

Comment: yesterday for some hours I had a hole in the top bar, where now the hat icon is. I guess the system was warming up for the hats

Comment: Better question: How did I end up getting the "Quarantine Hair" hat? It only says it's a secret hat.

Comment: @Mephistopheles I agree; it randomly showed up in my hat collection, and I can't find what it's for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This year there was no consultancy to see which sites wanted in or out.

It's a personal decision - if you don't want to play, you can click on the "No Hats For Me" link at the bottom corner of the popup that appears if you click on the snowflake icon.

Answer (score 3):

Considering that I just earned the Social Distancing <strike>hat</strike> mask here on Meta, it appears that we are.

Comment: The contests are system-wide. I don't think individual Stacks can opt out.